# How to recognize a custom method from an iOS built-in method

Tags: ios, methods

Lets say I define a class from UIViewController

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

So MyViewController used some of UIViewController class built-in methods for loading a view controller’s views such as

```
viewWillAppear:
viewDidAppear:
```

And some of my custom methods that I defined such as

```
elementsToAdd:
pressThis
```

Is there any way to recognize the custom method names from built-in methods? Is there any list of iOS reserved built-in method names for different classes?

Comment: Well, for one, you could check the documentation for the class you're subclassing - in this case, [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html).

Comment: I want to programmatically check this if possible. So I want to see if there is a more efficient way of doing it before me creating a list of the methods from the header files of classes.

Comment: Do you want a programmatic way to find out if your superclass implements a given method? Or do you want a programmatic way to list all of the methods to which your superclass responds? Also, can you give some background as to why you want this?

Comment: Why not markup all of your methods in such a way that a simple script can find them?

Comment: So for an iOS project, I used Objective-C runtime to get all the classes and loop through all the method names in each class. But for my own purposes, I want to distinguish between the built-in methods and the custom methods that are defined by developers. I want to programatically find out if the given method name is built-in method name or not.